# Closing my application After Exception shows using try,catch method VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have function that check internet connection before my application continue working, using ping sometimes my connection are limited and that make my program crash. i want to close my application when it happen. can you help me ?
this is my sample code

```
 If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then
        Try
            Dim pingreq As Ping = New Ping()
            Dim pinging As PingReply = pingreq.Send("www.google.com")
            Dim latency As Integer = pinging.RoundtripTime
            Dim status = pinging.ToString
        Catch err As PingException
            write_log(Date.Now.ToString("dd:MM:yyyy - HH:mm:ss") & "||" & "Connection Error" & err.ToString() & err.Message)
            If Not err Is Nothing Then
                Timer1.Stop()
                Me.Close()
                constat = 0
            End If
        End Try
    Else
        Timer1.Stop()
        Me.Close()
    End If
```

Comment: `If Not err Is Nothing Then` is not necessary. The whole point of `Try`, `Catch` is to handle your exceptions when they're thrown - therefore your exception will not be empty. Also, you don't need to do `PingException`, you can use the generic `Exception`.

Comment: okay i try to remove the if, then i try using generic exception. but the problem is another function in my program is need internet to work, so another exception show up, so how i can stop another exception ?

Comment: Encapsulate that method within another `Try Catch`... but you don't need to remove `Timer1.Stop()`, `Me.Close()`, etc. if you want to close your program.

Comment: Okay Thanks, Im sorry take so long to reply, my project halted for a while. i reopened, so thanks it's already done @AlexM.